# Are there no footnotes in Vancouver referencing?

Tags: citation-style

I just wanted to check if Vancouver referencing does not use footnotes. I saw online that the citations are just numbered and then the reference list is put at the end of the essay instead of footnotes throughout. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. See the last page of this pdf for an example of a Vancouver references section:

http://guides.lib.monash.edu/ld.php?content_id=14570618

In response to a comment below about the in-text citations coming after the punctuation, here is another example where they use brackets but don't mention if it is in-text citations (but the references section/end of essay references match the guide above). When I use Vancouver style in my own writing, Mendeley defaults in-text citations within the period.

http://editor.citationstyles.org/styleInfo/?styleId=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2Fstyles%2Fvancouver

Comment: The in-text references in square or round brackets go _after_ the punctuation? Very weird.